# c# internationalization text resources

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, globalization

I am building a c# windows forms application which can support multiple languages. In order to store all the string resources, I am using `.resx` files for each culture. I managed to make the application work but I read somewhere some time ago that resource string can also be stored in text files. Would you be so kind in explaining me how the strings should be written inside the text file and how should I load each text file for each culture? Thanks.

PS: I am a beginner so please, bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

In resx files you will get options to add files (from top left menu), there you can add text files from solution, which will be added on resx during build now you can change text file in the solution and on build that changes will be part of resx.

I had used in past one file per culture in the same resx and as soon as app come to know about culture i was loading corresponding text file from resx.

In text file I had "key:value" from which I was preparing dictionary and had cached it, that was easier to work with in my simple/small culture specific texts requirement.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I think he was not looking to add text files to resources, but to use text file instead of resources, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text files for resources for the news Win8 Apps. Not sure if that works for other plattforms too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

http://www.cnblogs.com/anorthwolf/archive/2010/08/23/1806686.html

```
static public string GetStringRegistryValue(string key, string defaultValue)
{
    RegistryKey rkCompany;
    RegistryKey rkApplication;
    rkCompany = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(SOFTWARE_KEY, 
                false).OpenSubKey(COMPANY_NAME, false);
    if( rkCompany != null )
    {
        rkApplication = rkCompany.OpenSubKey(APPLICATION_NAME, true);
        if( rkApplication != null )
        {
            foreach(string sKey in rkApplication.GetValueNames())
            {
                if( sKey == key )
                {
                return (string)rkApplication.GetValue(sKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```